# How to keep track of list changes in reminders app, like Name or Color - Swift and SwiftUI App

Tags: swift, swiftui, eventkit

I know there is the EKEventStoreChanged Event to keep track of changes in the Reminder-App. The only problem is that this event just get triggered, when a list in the reminder app gets created or deleted. Not edited.

Does anyone know how to keep track of editing changes, to update the SwiftUI View?

Thanks

The Observer I added so far:

`NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(forName: .EKEventStoreChanged, object: ReminderManager.shared.eventStore, queue: nil) { notification in self.storeChanged(notification) }`

Answer (score 0):

In SwiftUI use `onReceive` for notifications, e.g.

```
 .onReceive(NotificationCenter.default.publisher(for: EKEventStoreChanged))
        { obj in
```

The docs state you should call `refresh` on the reminder and if it returns `true`, refetch it to get the changes and merge them into your edits. If it returns `false` it wasn't changed so you don't need to refetch it.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsnotification/name/1507525-ekeventstorechanged

More info here

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/eventkit/updating_with_notifications

FYI there is a `EKEventViewController` that you could wrap in a `UIViewControllerRepresentable`, here is an example:

https://nemecek.be/blog/40/how-to-use-ekeventeditviewcontroller-in-swiftui#complete-code

(Note you will need to fix the `Coordinator(self)` mistake, `self` will go out of date the next time this struct is init.